# iOS ARC application and one line or two initializations of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm curious but does the one line initialization below and being added to an array have any memory impact in a ARC application?  Is either one ok, or should I use one over the other?

```
[events addObject:[Event getEvent:item]];
```

or

```
Event *event = [Event getEvent:item];
[events addObject:event];
```

Comment: The first line probably should be `[events addObject:[Event getEvent:item]];` ?

Comment: Yes thanks copy and paste mistake

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`...  Reserved for pass by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[Event getEvent:item]` returns an object that the caller does not own (a +0 retained object, it could be an autoreleased object).

In the first case, which probably should be

```
[events addObject:[Event getEvent:item]];
```

this object is passed to the `addObject` method of `NSArray`, which retains the object.

In the second case

```
Event *event = [Event getEvent:item];
[events addObject:event];
```

the first line creates a strong reference (retaining the object). (This is
explained in [4.2. Semantics](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics)
in the "Clang/ARC" documentation.)
Then the `addObject`
call in the second line retains it again. When the local variable `event` goes
out of scope, the strong reference is destroyed and the object released.

So the net result is the same. Both methods are *equally correct* with respect to the 
memory semantics. They differ at most in one additional retain/release call,
but there is no difference in the "memory impact".

You should choose whatever you understand better.

*Note also* that the ARC compiler is quite clever to optimize/remove unnecessary
retain/release calls, therefore I strongly assume that in the release build
there will be no difference at all in the compiled code.

Comment: The last sentence is key!

Answer (score 4):

Both will be compiled to the same binary in your example so there is no difference at all.

The only difference is that

```
Event *event = [Event getEvent:item];
```

yields an [l-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29) so you'll be able to obtain its address if necessary while the second yields an r-value. But if you don't use the former as an l-value it will be optimised to the same instructions.

What I mean is that you are able to do if you need it:

```
Event *event = [Event getEvent:item];
Event **event = &event;
```

Comment: Note that with the Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) in Objective-C, assigning a value to a `__strong` pointer (which is the default) can have "side effects", such as increasing the retain count.

Comment: That may not be the case in the release code due to compiler optimizations. The event variable may not even exist, it may be optimized out. See the answer by @Martin R